# How to add a decimal in excel (2016) to the left for a whole column and also add the whole column up 112 = 1.12

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet I'm trying to add up all the numbers and add a decimal point to the left for rows e2-e467 (example 112 = 1.12) I just copied and paste the 466 numbers and don't want to go through them one by one to add the decimal in it. I was able to add the column up but wasn't able to add he decimal to the left of all numbers. I found you can add a decimal to the right but not to the left.

Comment: Use the following formula `=E2/100` then populate down. If you need the result in column `E`, then copy and paste special the values only

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in F2 and copy down:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(E2,1)&"."&RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)-1))
```

It breaks the number into a string and adds a decimal to the left. It then converts it back into a number so you can sum the column. It will work regardless of the number length.